# how to prevent itemeditor destruction?

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component, itemeditor

My custom item editor opens a titlewindow (too much stuff to show in an inline editor) which obviously steal the focus, so I get a itemeditend event and the datagrid destroy the editor at the wrong (for me) time. I think to have to keep the itemeditor alive until the titlewindow job is done, but how? DataGridEvent reason is "other" and livedocs said preventDefault() [can't help](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/celleditor_7.html#196893).
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

set the popupwindow.owner=this (the renderer) and it will not be destroyed